# Recover AWS Root email given AWS CLI credential

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have another PC which has AWS CLI setup. I can still access the account and when I do `aws s3 ls` it lists all the buckets that I have. However, this is not connected to my current AWS root account. I don't know which account this AWS CLI credential belong to

Is there any possible way to recover or a hint so I can get the email address of the root account this CLI profile associated with?

I have tried `aws sts get-caller-identity` but I can't still figure out what my root email is

**Edit:** I found a user that I can sign in to the web console, but is there any way to recover the root's email address?

I have tried live chat with AWS billing and account, but they are unable to help.

In summary my situation is:

1. I have an account with access to AWS CLI and web console
2. This account is not the root account

How can I recover my root account?

Comment: Can you access the billing and find the email address where the billing is send to?

Comment: @Lucasz sadly no, only the root account has access to billing

Comment: [Access an AWS account if the administrator left the company](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/admin-left-need-acct-access/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, no it is not possible to recover the email of the root account for security reason

Not even AWS account support is able to help. I'm not sure if it can be escalated somewhere, but I can imagine the process will not be straightforward and taking into account it's a personal account, I don't think it's worth it

So my advice to those having the same question:

1. If you have a non root user with admin privilege, disable all running services to avoid incurring future charges
2. simply create a new account

I know it's not the ideal solution, but I don't think there's any other way

Answer (score 2):

If your AWS accounts are attached to an AWS Organisation, you can also see the aws root email address in the OU screen in the tree view:

https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/organizations/v2/home/accounts

This should list the root email of all of your Organisations associated accounts.

Answer (score 2):

you can recover the root email, by creating an Organization if the account is not in Organization yet.
it will show the account's root email then in the Organization interface.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the account id of your credentials with STS.

With AWS IAM CLI you can get the users which you can try to login with. It might be that a email address is used as username

Answer (score 0):

If you have AWS CLI setup run the following command: `aws organizations create-organization` the MasterAccountEmail should default to the root user's email.

note:  this assumes the account that has CLI setup has the required privalleges